# Cassandra selecting by reverse order of clustering order

Tags: cassandra, cql, scylla

I wan't to select rows by the order of ASC and DESC but cassandra data orders are fixed .

I use ScyllaDB.

My imaginary scenario of problem :

I have a table :

`CREATE TABLE tbl(A text , B text , C text , primary key(A,B,C))`

After inserting datas my table is :

[image]

Now i want to select top 1 ( or x ) item of row ( A - B - 3 )
And after that select bottom 1 ( or x ) item of row ( A - B - 3 ).

C order is ASC and it's fixed ! 
now i try to select bottom 1 item :

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE A='A' AND B='B' AND C > '3' LIMIT 1 ;`

but selecting top of ( A-B-3 ) is my problem

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE A='A' AND B='B' AND C < '3' ???`

Is there any solution for selecting top of item in cassandra ?

Comment: I think your problem here is that you might be trying to compare with textual values. Can you provide an additions to the question in terms of what results you are seeing and what results you'd expect to see?

Comment: in my real table C field is date ( the date of inserting row in table ) but the gape of dates is not equal . i want select top and bottom of a row

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you. But there is an `ORDER BY` clause which should be usable on C. You can also just read the values of `A='A' AND B='B'` until c >= 3 and reduce fetch size if concerned about waste.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)) . when i was tried to order result using ```... ORDER BY C...``` i get some error . now my correct query is ``` .... ORDER BY B DESC, C DESC``` or ```...ORDER BY B ASC C ASC``` ( matches Clustering order or reverse )